# Is there any way to force natbib to be compatible with a SBC template?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, templates

I have to use the [SBC](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sbc-conferences-template/blbxwjwzdngr) template in my work, and I would like to use some features of *natbib*. However, the template is not compatible.

> Is there any way to use *natbib* in the [SBC](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sbc-conferences-template/blbxwjwzdngr) template?

I would like to use the \citep function

(Source of the template is [here](https://www.sbc.org.br/documentos-da-sbc/summary/169-templates-para-artigos-e-capitulos-de-livros/878-modelosparapublicaodeartigos).)

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible really. See [Why does natbib conflict with sbc.bst?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/98982) for some discussion.

Comment: If you don't need to use the `sbc` bibliography style, then you can load `natbib` after you load `sbc-template` and then use an appropriate bibliography style (e..g `apalike`).